# Javascript Multi Sub Array

Tags: javascript

i have a javascript code which generates dynamic sub arrays.

```
function createArray() {

    var myArr = new Object();
    myArr[0] = createSubArray('apple');
    myArr[1] = createSubArray('Mango');
    myArr[2] = createSubArray('Pineapple');
    myArr[3] = createSubArray('Grape');
    document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(myArr);
    return myArr;

}


function createSubArray(name){
    var arr = new Object();
    elems = document.getElementsByName(name);
    for (var i=0;i<elems.length;i++){
        if (elems[i].checked){
            arr[name] =  elems[i].value;
            arr['price'] =  elems[i].getAttribute('data-price');
        }
    }
    return arr;

}
```

And i got the output as below

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'apple' => string 'light' (length=5)
      'price' => string '10' (length=2)
  1 => 
    array
      'apple' => string 'light1' (length=5)
      'price' => string '10' (length=2)
  2 => 
    array
      'Mango' => string 'dark' (length=4)
      'price' => string '40' (length=2)
  3 => 
    array
      'Pineapple' => string 'dark' (length=4)
      'price' => string '60' (length=2)
  4 => 
    array
      'Grape' => string 'dark' (length=4)
      'price' => string '80' (length=2)
```

But i need to array to be like below

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'apple' => string 'light' (length=5)
       0 => 
           array
            'apple' => string 'light' (length=5)
            'price' => string '10' (length=2)
       1 => 
           array
            'apple' => string 'light1' (length=5)
            'price' => string '10' (length=2)
  1 => 
    array
      'Mango' => string 'light' (length=5)
       0 => 
           array
            'Mango' => string 'light' (length=5)
            'price' => string '10' (length=2)
  2 => 
    array
      'Pineapple' => string 'light' (length=5)
       0 => 
           array
            'Pineapple' => string 'light' (length=5)
            'price' => string '10' (length=2)
```

so i have changed the javascript like this

```
function createArray()
{
    var myArr = new Object();
    var _tempa = new Array();
    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
     for (var i=0;i<elems.length;i++)
     {  if (elems[i].checked){
         _tempa.push(elems[i].getAttribute('name'));
            myArr[i] = createSubArray1(_tempa);
          }
      }
     document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(myArr);
    return myArr;
} 

function createSubArray1(namearr){

    var arr1 = new Object();
    for (var j=0;i<namearr.length;j++){
    var elems = document.getElementsByName(name[j]);
    for (var i=0;i<elems.length;i++){
        if (elems[i].checked)
        {
        arr1[elems[i].getAttribute('data-gpname')] =  createSubArray(elems[i].getAttribute('name'));
        }
    }
    }
    return arr1;
}

 function createSubArray(name){
    var arr = new Object();
    var elems = document.getElementsByName(name);
    for (var i=0;i<elems.length;i++){
        if (elems[i].checked)
        {
        arr['productname'] =  elems[i].value;
        arr['price'] =  elems[i].getAttribute('data-price');
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

After this i am getting the out put like below

```
[{},{}]
```

My Html Is Below

```
<form method="post">
Apple
<input type="radio" onclick="createArray()" id="one" name="apple" data-gpname="apple" data-price="10" value="light"/> Light
<input type="radio" onclick="createArray()" id="two" name="apple" data-gpname="apple" data-price="20" value="dark" /> Dark
<input type="radio" onclick="createArray()" id="one1" name="apple1" data-gpname="apple"  data-price="120" value="light2"/> Light11
<input type="radio" onclick="createArray()" id="two1" name="apple1" data-gpname="apple" data-price="210" value="dark1" /> Dark22
<input type="text" id="appleqty" name="appleqty" value="" />
<br>
Mango
<input type="radio" onclick="createArray()" id="three" name="Mango" data-gpname="Mango"  data-price="30" value="light"/> Light
<input type="radio" onclick="createArray()" id="one" name="Mango" data-gpname="Mango" data-price="40" value="dark" /> Dark
<input type="text" id="Mangoqty" name="Mangoqty" value="" />
<br>
Pine Apple
<input type="radio" onclick="createArray()" id="four" name="Pineapple" data-gpname="Pineapple" data-price="50" value="light"/> Light
<input type="radio" onclick="createArray()" id="five" name="Pineapple" data-gpname="Pineapple" data-price="60" value="dark" /> Dark
<input type="text" id="Pineappleqty" name="Pineappleqty" value="" />
<br>
Grape
<input type="radio" onclick="createArray()" id="six" name="Grape" data-gpname="Grape" data-price="70" value="light"/> Light
<input type="radio" onclick="createArray()" id="seven" name="Grape" data-gpname="Grape" data-price="80" value="dark" /> Dark
<input type="text" id="Pineappleqty" name="Pineappleqty" value="" />

<textarea name="a" id="a" cols="50"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="se" value="se" />
</form>
```

I have used `php json_decode` to get the array Structure

Comment: Please don't write a novel but short, meaningful question…

Comment: I agree with @feeela the problem could be expressed more succinctly, perhaps by reducing the size of the test data for a start.

Comment: A well explained question is always better than a vague-short one. Also this a specific case, which means a short question is not really possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope [this](http://jsbin.com/ugusab/12) will help you. The output is same like you told [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/5451353#5451353).

The source of this page is [here](http://jsbin.com/ugusab/1/edit#/ugusab/12/edit).

I made a another [sample](http://jsbin.com/ugusab/12/edit#/ugusab/16/edit) based on your comments. Try this and let me know.

HTML:

```
<form method="post" id="myform">
Apple
<input type="radio" onclick="constructJSON(this.name)" id="one" name="apple" data-gpname="apple" data-price="10" value="light"/> Light
<input type="radio" onclick="constructJSON(this.name)" id="two" name="apple" data-gpname="apple" data-price="20" value="dark" /> Dark
<input type="radio" onclick="constructJSON(this.name)" id="one1" name="apple1" data-gpname="apple"  data-price="120" value="light2"/> Light11
<input type="radio" onclick="constructJSON(this.name)" id="two1" name="apple1" data-gpname="apple" data-price="210" value="dark1" /> Dark22
<input type="text" id="appleqty" name="appleqty" value="" />
<br>
Mango
<input type="radio" onclick="constructJSON(this.name)" id="three" name="Mango" data-gpname="Mango"  data-price="30" value="light"/> Light
<input type="radio" onclick="constructJSON(this.name)" id="one" name="Mango" data-gpname="Mango" data-price="40" value="dark" /> Dark
<input type="text" id="Mangoqty" name="Mangoqty" value="" />
<br>
Pine Apple
<input type="radio" onclick="constructJSON(this.name)" id="four" name="Pineapple" data-gpname="Pineapple" data-price="50" value="light"/> Light
<input type="radio" onclick="constructJSON(this.name)" id="five" name="Pineapple" data-gpname="Pineapple" data-price="60" value="dark" /> Dark
<input type="text" id="Pineappleqty" name="Pineappleqty" value="" />
<br>
Grape
<input type="radio" onclick="constructJSON(this.name)" id="six" name="Grape" data-gpname="Grape" data-price="70" value="light"/> Light
<input type="radio" onclick="constructJSON(this.name)" id="seven" name="Grape" data-gpname="Grape" data-price="80" value="dark" /> Dark
<input type="text" id="Pineappleqty" name="Pineappleqty" value="" />

<textarea name="a" id="a" cols="50"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="se" value="se" />

</form>
```

Script:

```
var rgArray = [];
function constructJSON(name)
{
  rgArray.push(name);
  var myArray = {};
  var productData = {};
  productData['products'] = createArray();
  $("#a").html(JSON.stringify(productData));
}

function createArray(){
  var group = {};
  var product;
  var data;
  var hasValue = false;
  $rgArray = $(rgArray);
  $.each($rgArray, function(i, gp){
    product = {};
    var el = "input[data-gpname='"+gp+"']";
    $el = $(el);
    hasValue = false;
    $.each($el, function(i, item){
      
      if(item.checked){
          data = {};
          data.name = $(item).val();
          data.price = $(item).attr("data-price");
            
          hasValue = true;
          product[$(item).attr("name")] = data;
        }
    });
    if(hasValue) group[gp] = product;
  });
  return group;
}
```

Comment: ok its working but this line `var rgArray = ['apple', 'Mango', 'Pineapple', 'Grape'];` should be dynamic the array value should be given from the radio button name variable

Comment: Is there any specific reason for getting radio button name dynamic?

Comment: because all the radio buttone is generated dynimicaly

Comment: ok, you want to generate the json for all the radio buttons which are selected at once? I don't think you can get all at once. You can generate the output for what is currently selected if everything is dynamic.

Comment: if any check box is selected in that i will provide a variable name called as data-proname for var rgArray i need that value to be inserted in rgArray

Answer (score 3):

**Updated Demo with output in Textarea**: http://jsfiddle.net/zZxaR/13/

**Note**: Added a couple of methods to pretty print the array in the console

**Disclaimer**: Used a bit of jQuery to make the traversal easier. Can be done just as easily without using it too.

**Code**:

```
function createArray() {
    var myArray = [], i = 0, temp;
    while(i < 4) myArray[i++] = [];
    myArray[0]['apple'] = '';
    myArray[1]['mango'] = '';
    myArray[2]['grape'] = '';
    myArray[3]['pineapple'] = '';

    $('input[data-gpname]:checked').each(function() {
        var gp = $(this).attr('data-gpname').toLowerCase();
        for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            if(myArray[i][gp] != undefined) {
                myArray[i][gp] = $(this).attr('value');
                temp = [];
                temp[gp] = $(this).attr('value');
                temp['price'] = $('#' + gp + 'qty').val();
                myArray[i].push(temp);
            }
        }
    });

    console.log(myArray);
    prettyPrint(myArray);
}
```

Comment: i need the json output like this http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/5451353#5451353

Comment: why does this answer contain canc... I mean jQuery?

Comment: just to make the traversal a little easy. it can easily be done without too. there is a disclaimer for jquery usage right at the beginning of the answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

For the multi sub array I created an [example](http://jsbin.com/ugusab/1) and code [here](http://jsbin.com/ugusab/1/edit)

Bellow is just FYI:

In jQuery form [serialize array](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) function is used to print/show the values in array format.

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  console.log($(this).serializeArray());
  return false;
});
```

Comment: i think you dont understand the question

Answer (score -1):

try this code i have just edited it a little

```
function createSubArray(name){
    var arr = [];

    elems = document.getElementsByName(name);
    for (var i=0;i<elems.length;i++){
        if (elems[i].checked){
            var o = {}
            o[name] =  elems[i].value;
            o['price'] =  elems[i].getAttribute('data-price');
            arr.push(o);
        }
    }
    return arr;

}
function createArray() {

    var myArr = [];
    myArr[0] = createSubArray('apple');
    myArr[1] = createSubArray('Mango');
    myArr[2] = createSubArray('Pineapple');
    myArr[3] = createSubArray('Grape');
    document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(myArr);
    return myArr;
}
```

earlier you were returning an object from the `createSubArray` method which i think was the mistake
i have edited it to return an array with all the objects

this is the JSON string that i was getting

```
[
    [
        {
            "apple": "light",
            "price": "10"
        },
        {
            "apple": "dark",
            "price": "20"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "Mango": "light",
            "price": "30"
        },
        {
            "Mango": "dark",
            "price": "40"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "Pineapple": "light",
            "price": "50"
        },
        {
            "Pineapple": "dark",
            "price": "60"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "Grape": "light",
            "price": "70"
        },
        {
            "Grape": "dark",
            "price": "80"
        }
    ]
]
```

Comment: ok i think the top level object should have been an array too.. i have edited my ans and the response string that i was getting have a look

Comment: not its not the correct answer check here i need like this http://jsfiddle.net/yJkEE/

Comment: kindly check the question where 'But i need to array to be like below' is written

Comment: yeah i have seen that.. i think that is also not correct. can you please add a valid JSON string to teh question like the one you want?

Comment: the above is not an json its an array

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16947/discussion-between-s-varun-and-parv-sharma)